# Pros and cons of using ARM assembly for Iphone development?

Tags: iphone, ios, assembly, arm

I'm experimenting with `ARM` assembly language, during this I often use inline assembly blocks in `Objective-C` code for my first iOS 6 small pet project. During this I wondered:

1. Is it reasonable at all to use ARM assembly in large commercial iOS projects?
2. Can I optimise some bottlenecks with it and exceed compiler in this?
3. What are some common guidelines or best practicies of using assembly language for iOS: vectorization, [NEON](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/CJAJIIGG.html), `SIMD`, media optimisation (image shrinking and etc.)?

Comment: Languages are ultimately abstractions from ASM.  The only really useful thing ASM is for in iOS development is NEON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone is just a small computer so the trade-offs of using assembler are exactly the same as with any other machine.

The general answer has to be no, you don't want to be using assembler.

Having said that, there are always exceptions where hand-tuned, very low level code might be faster. Make sure you use Instruments to correctly identify your bottlenecks and that you've tuned your code using higher-level techniques before you start.

Use special hardware features where it makes sense, but bear in mind that you don't need to use assembler to get the benefits of most of them.

Comment: Another exception is for doing fun projects.  Objective-C is a really ugly language, assembly is definitely a step in programming enjoyment.  Obviously if it's a for pay project Objective-C will win out for productivity.

Comment: It can be useful for things like physics engines and other heavy math (where you can directly access the ARM vector operations) but for anything else the compiler will always generate better code than you can. In any case measure first, optimize later.